# How to immediately remove cookies from browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I am using cookies for my website.
I need to remove cookies immediately from browser for that i use this Code in C#

### Code for removal of cookie

```
Response.Cookies["OptDepth"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-30);
```

after execution of this code if i use this code

### Code to check value of deleted cookie

```
Request.Cookies["OptDepth"].value;
```

then it gives me the value of specified cookie.
I need to remove cookies immediately from browser.
How can i do this.

Comment: Use jQuery
$.cookie("name", null)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Are you running both lines of code in the same request?

Comment: No both lines are in different request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we change the name of that cookie with null then it works.

### Code

```
Request.Cookies["OptDepth"].Name = null;
```

Now problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Use Simple Code to replace cookies with expiry date:

```
if (Request.Cookies["OptDepth"] != null)
{
    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("OptDepth");
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
}
```

Here is an msdn detail link.[Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When adding a cookie ;

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("try");

                cookie.Values["foo"] = "foo";
                DateTime date = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-30);
                cookie.Expires = date;
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

When Reading the cookie;

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["try"];
```

You will see the cookie is null.

Comment: This is not working.By the way i got a solution.
Request.Cookies["OptDepth"].Name = null;

Comment: I have compiled the code above and then wrote it,maybe browser cache is a problem. But glad that you solved the problem.